# Custom RequireHttps and testing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, https

I have a custom Authorize attribute. This attribute checks if the user also have permissions to that action based on the parameters of the attribute.  In some times inside the custom Authorize attribute I want to requiere HTTPS or redirect to it. Is there any way to do this with the AuthorizationContext?

How can I test it? and debug it? Is there a simple tutorial to use SSL in my developer machine with VS 2010?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RequireHttps will redirect HOWEVER it doesn't stop the browser  from sending data non-ssl first which could be captured. Note that for post actions this wont work right out of the box either.

To install ssl, simply generate your cert and import it. Do you have a subscription to pluralsight.com? i have a course up there where I go over the steps for requiressl and installing ssl on local machine (theres a 30 day free trial too)

If you just want the details here : )
theres a nice powershell script to use:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/491/powershell-snap-in-configuring-ssl-with-the-iis-powershell-snap-in/

Comment: ok.... but theres is any way to achive this in a custom Authorize Attribute, and how?

Comment: You want to require ssl in an attribute? Why not just ensure your entire site is ssl by using RequireSslAttribute as a global filter to apply to your whole site as opposed to trying to include this in an attribute. You can do it, since you can redirect inside of a filter:  filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect for example but is this where you want this to be handled as opposed to ensuring your entire site is protected or your login page? Remember if you are using say, forms auth, your token is constantly sent over non-ssl connections anyways that could easily be sniffed.